# kotlin android start new service

Tags: android, kotlin, android-components

By using the below code, I'm trying to start new service from a `Broadcast receiver`, but the service does not seem to start. What is the **correct way** to **start** a service in **kotlin**?

```
val intent = Intent(context, LocationService::class.java)
 if (context != null) {
      context.startService(intent)
 }
```

Comment: Is the service registered in the manifest?

Comment: Make sure that `startService` returns non-null value, this will indicate that service was started. Keep in mind that `startService` is deprecated in Android O and will throw exception for `targetSdk 26`.

Answer (score 16):

try this

```
 val intent = Intent(context, LocationService::class.java)
 if (context != null) {
      context.startService(intent)
 }
```

And don't forget to register your `service` in `manifest` file

```
 <service  android:name="packageName.LocationService"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use safe access compression in kotlin:

```
val intent = Intent(context, LocationService::class.java)
context?.startService(intent)
```

Also define your service in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Put declaration of service in AndroidManifest.xml file 
i.e `<service android:name=".LocationService"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your service in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest ...>
   <application ...>
      <service
          android:name="package.LocationService">
      </service>
   </application>
</manifest>
```